# how future get() method works with timeout

Tags: java

I am a bit confused how Future.get(timeout) works as per the definition it would through an exception after specified timeout time, but its not happening in my test cases.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
 import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CallableExample {

public static class WordLengthCallable implements Callable<String> {
    private String word;
    private long waiting;

    public WordLengthCallable(String word, long waiting) {
        this.word = word;
        this.waiting = waiting;
    }

    public String call() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(waiting);
        return word;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    args = new String[] { "i", "am", "in", "love" };
    long[] waitArr = new long[] { 3000, 3440, 2500, 3000 };
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    Set<Future<String>> set = new LinkedHashSet<Future<String>>();
    int i = 0;
    for (String word : args) {
        Callable<String> callable = new WordLengthCallable(word, waitArr[i++]);
        Future<String> future = pool.submit(callable);
        set.add(future);
    }
    String sum = "";
    for (Future<String> future : set) {
        try {
            sum += future.get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + ", ";
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Result : " + sum);
}
}
```

output "am, in,"

it behaves differently on changing waiting time in array( timeArr values). when to use get with timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for-loop you wait for the first future to complete. This may take 2000 millis. At this time all the other threads will sleep. Hence, all the values of the other threads are 2000 millis less. Then you wait another 2000 millis and perhaps the future you wait for returns. Hence, two or more threads will succeed.

In each iteration of your loop you donate 2000 millis to the other thread. Only if one future returns successfully, you donate less to the remaining futures. If you would like to observe all futures to fail, due to the 2000 millis timeout, you would have to process them in parallel as well.

If you change some of your code this way:

```
Set<Callable<String>> tasks = new HashSet<>();
for (String word : args) {
    tasks.add(new WordLengthCallable(word, waitArr[i++]));
}
List<Future<String>> futures = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)
        .invokeAll(tasks, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

you should observe that none of the tasks will succeed, due to the wait times of:

```
3000, 3440, 2500, 3000
```

for each `Callable` created, which are all greater than 2000.

Comment: execution is quite similar as per your description but why the last task having wait time of 3000ms throwing exception, please justify.

Comment: got it, execution of 4th task will start after 2500ms and at the time of 4th future turn it would complete 3440-2500=940ms sleep time still it requires 2060ms time to complete resulting in timeout :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Thanks to @RQube for warning me about thread's execution order as 3. thread will be finished before 1., 4. thread will start after 3.'s finish instead of 1.

First of all your thread pool's size is 3. This means your 4. Future will wait 3. to finish.

Lets assume there is no time consuming work other than thread waits. Execution will be like this:

1. Future - 3000ms wait time - This will throw timeout exception but keep running since you are not terminating it on timeout. So your 4. Future still waiting for one thread to finish.
   Total execution time: 2000ms
2. Future - 1440ms wait since you already wait 2000ms - This will return as you see in your output "am". Also at 2500ms mark 3. Future will be executed and 4. Future will be started at 2500ms mark.
   Total execution time: 3440ms
3. Future - no wait time since we already wait 3440ms this will return immediately. 
   Total execution time: 3440ms.
4. Future - 2060ms wait time to finish since this has been started at 2500ms mark and after start 940ms has passed. This will timeout after 2000ms(at 2940ms of wait)

As you can see just 2. and 3. Futures will return when you call get() but actually all of them is executed.

Sorry for bad formatting and any typos, as i am writing on mobile.

Comment: thanks for the time, after few more R&D and with the help of @harmlezz I get to know the scenario. its quite same as per your description but the 4th task will start when one of the first three task having minimum wait time will finish. since the 3rd task has minimum wait time of 2500ms so the 4th task will start after 2500ms rather than 3000ms.